# NSScrollview DocumentView AutoresizingMask

Tags: nsscrollview, autoresizingmask

In my NSScrollView, I'm setting the document view to an NSView. However the content is always in the bottom left of the scrollview, I have tried setting the NSView's AutoresizingMask but no lock. Q: How can I set an AutoresizingMask in a NSScrollview Document view?

Comment: `NSScrollView` is one of the dumbest implementations of a scroll container I've ever witnessed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. This is how I solved it.

```
NSView *documentView = [NSView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
[documentView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[documentView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];

[myScrollView setDocumentView:documentView];
```